# Asio TCP server crash on DLL unload

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm using the standalone [Asio](http://think-async.com) library to host a simple TCP server. The code lives inside a dynamic library which is loaded by a host application I don't have control over.

The library exposes an `Open` and `Close` function, which the host application should call after loading/before unloading the library.
In the `Open` function, I run the `asio::io_service` in a separate thread:

```
// start accepting connections
server.accept();

// start the asio service in a new thread
serviceThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this]() {
    ioService.run();
});
```

In the `Close` function, I stop the service and join the thread:

```
// stop the asio service
ioService.stop();
serviceThread->join();
```

The server's `accept` function is implemented as follows:

```
void Server::accept() {
    acceptor.async_accept(socket, [this](std::error_code err) {
        if (!err) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(sessionsMutex);
            sessions.emplace_back(new Session(*this, ioService, std::move(socket)));
        }

        accept();
    });
}
```

Other functions to be called by the `asio::io_service` are implemented similarly, i.e. a lambda function binding `this` is passed to an asio `async` function.

This code works fine when the host application calls `Open` and `Close` as required.
However, sometimes, the host application does not call the `Close` function before unloading the library, leading to a segmentation fault caused by a bad memory read:

```
Thread 14 Crashed:
0   com.                            0x0000000121f1b14b asio::detail::scheduler::post_immediate_completion(asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, bool) + 27 (scheduler.ipp:281)
1   com.                            0x0000000121f1f17c void asio::io_context::executor_type::post<asio::detail::work_dispatcher<myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>, std::__1::allocator<void> >(asio::detail::work_dispatcher<myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>&&, std::__1::allocator<void> const&) const + 124 (io_context.hpp:270)
2   com.                            0x0000000121f1f027 asio::async_result<std::__1::decay<myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>::type, void ()>::return_type asio::post<asio::io_context::executor_type, myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>(asio::io_context::executor_type const&, myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3&&, std::__1::enable_if<is_executor<asio::io_context::executor_type>::value, void>::type*) + 87 (post.hpp:58)
3   com.                            0x0000000121f11cb2 asio::async_result<std::__1::decay<myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>::type, void ()>::return_type asio::post<asio::io_context, myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3>(asio::io_context&, myproject::Server::Session::write()::$_3&&, std::__1::enable_if<is_convertible<asio::io_context&, asio::execution_context&>::value, void>::type*) + 50 (post.hpp:69)
[...]
```

What are my options? Is there a cross-platform way to detect the unloading of the library (must work on macOS and Windows), which allows me to perform the clean-up in any case?
Can I modify my usage of Asio to deal with this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to keep the library loaded as long as its code is running, e.g. `LoadLibrary` when starting a thread to increment the reference count, and [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread) when the worker thread dies.

The host application can be as unhappy as it likes that the library didn't unload when asked.... but it is the one that broke the rule by not calling `Close()`.

And no, there's nothing even remotely cross-platform about this.  But handling of dynamic libraries is quite OS-specific.  Maybe you can find a cross-platform wrapper for dynamic library handling in particular.

Comment: What are the macOS equivalents of these functions? I'm developing on macOS

Comment: @CrushedPixel: I don't know names of macOS functions, that's why the Windows-specific functions are named inside of an "i.e." clause.  They're a starting point, from which you can find the right functions on all the platforms you care about.